# How do I freeze a function's variables in a closure?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, closures

I am working on a calendar which supports repeated occurrences, so the intended behavior is that when someone checks the "done" checkbox for one activity on one day it hides that day's instance of the activity and leaves the other ones untouched.

The actual, seen behavior is that when someone checks any checkbox, it deletes the last day's instance of that activity, and I'm pretty sure this is because a function is accessing the most recent variables of a loop in a closure, instead of the values held by those variables when it was being run. The relevant code snippet is:

```
for(var index = 0; index < elements.length; ++index)
    {
    var split_id = elements[index].id.split('_');
    var id = Number(split_id[1]);
    var day = split_id[2];
    var date = split_id[3];
    var month = split_id[4];
    var year = split_id[5];
    elements[index].onclick = function()
        {
        alert(id + '_' + day + '_' + date + '_' + month + '_' + year);
        if (calendar[id][2].indexOf(id + '_' + day + '_' + date + '_' + month + '_' + year) === -1)
            {
            calendar[id][2][calendar[id][2].length] = id + '_' + day + '_' + date + '_' + month + '_' + year;
            }
        save_all();
        update_calendar_display();
        }
    }
```

What are my best options to have the onclick function access the variables it had when it was created, not when the loop exited?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u didn't use any closure in ur code. for loop doesn't define a scope. try this

```
function clickFunction(id, date, day, month, year) {  
        return function() {
          alert(id + '_' + day + '_' + date + '_' + month + '_' + year);
          if (calendar[id][2].indexOf(id + '_' + day + '_' + date + '_' + month + '_' + year) === -1) {
              calendar[id][2][calendar[id][2].length] = id + '_' + day + '_' + date + '_' + month + '_' + year;
            }
          save_all();
          update_calendar_display();  
        }  
}
```

then

```
elements[index].onclick = clickFunction(id, date, day, mo)
```